# IIS7 stops working after 5 requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Here is my problem:

I have just been brought onto a massive asp.net C# project and I've been charged with fixing some performance issues (not my area of expertise).  More specifically after 5 - 7 redirects/ajax calls the web server stops responding and the whole page (and eventually the browser) freezes.

I don't think this is a coding issue as I've set up break points in a few pages (Page_Load method) and after the 5 requests it does not even reach the break points.

I don't believe this is related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031614/ie7-stops-making-network-requests-after-a-while) as I've increased the browser's maximum connections per server parameter and I got the same behavior. Furthermore after these 5 request in one browser IE, the application stops working in FF as well.

This is not a resource issue as the w3wp.exe process never exceeds 500MB memory.

One thing I've noticed when using Fiddler and other tools to monitor the requests is that the server takes a very long time when loading image files (png, jpg). I don't know if this is relevant.

I've enabled failed request tracing on the server and the only thing I've noticed is that some request fail with a 401 error even dough I've set Anonymous Authentication to enabled.
Here is the exact message

```
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 

 ModuleName     ManagedPipelineHandler 

 Notification   128 
 HttpStatus     401 
 HttpReason     Unauthorized 
 HttpSubStatus  0 
 ErrorCode      0 

 ConfigExceptionInfo

 Notification   EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER

 ErrorCode       The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
```

This message is sometimes thrown with ModuleName: ScriptModule

I have already wasted 2 days on this thing and I'm running out of ideas so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: five requests should be enough for anybody.

Comment: Your reason for hypothesizing that it's not a coding issue does not seem sound.

Comment: @Matt - not at all helpful, but upvoted for teh funneh.

Comment: After the browser has crashed, is it possible to open up an other browser and continue working as normal (well.. another 5 page requests?)

Comment: Does the server recover after a minute or two or does it stay "locked up" until you iisreset?

Comment: No even if i open a completely different browser it does not work

Comment: For the actual browser to crash, it would seem that server is sending data to the browser that it needs to process in some fashion, if the server got locked into an infinite code loop (continually sending out this data) then that could cause the browser to crash. Can you open a new tab in the browser and browse as normal?

Comment: It stays loked untill i iisreset or i recycle the AppPool. I've also tried changing the apppool Managed Pipe Line mode

Comment: I would bet that there is a code issue causing it to go into an infinite loop

Comment: @Magrangs - sounds plausible. Would be interesting to drop WireShark or something on the client and see if it's getting hammered with traffic from IIS.

Comment: Sounds like some root issue with a pervasive/copied code set - I want to see some code here (client and server side)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue finally. Here is what I did:

1. Experimented with IIS settings and App_Pool recycling and noticed that there is nothing wrong with the way it handles requests that actually reach it.
2. I focused on the Http.sys module and noticed that in the log files there were a lot of Timer_ConnectionIdle and Client_Reset errors.
3. After some more experimentation and a lot of Google searches, I accidentally found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439063/iis-asp-net-website-managedpipelinehandler-error-an-operation-was-attempted) and it solved my issue. As the answer suggests the problem was caused by the AVG antivirus installed and incorrectly configured on the server.

Thanks for all the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Like any large generic problem, your best bet in diagnosing the issue is to figure out how to break down the issue into smaller parts, how to hypothesize the issues, and how to validate or invalidate your hypotheses. My first inclination would be to hypothesize that the server-side processes in this particular are taking a long time, causing your client requests to block, making the whole thing seem frozen.

From there, I would attempt to replicate the long running server side processes by creating isolated client side tests - perhaps if the URLs are HTTP gets, I would test the same URLs individually. If they were HTTP posts, I'd create an isolated test form if feasible to see what happens with each request. If a long running server side process is found then you have a starting point.

If there are no long running server side processes then it may be JavaScript / client side coding issues that need to be looked into. But definitely when you're working a large, unfamiliar project, your best bet is to figure out how to break down the issue into  smaller components that can then be tested

Answer (score 0):

If it's ajax calls that are causing your browser to freeze, make sure they are not `blocking` ajax calls.

Comment: Most Ajax calls are done from JQuery with Http handlers and most are asynchronous and with a 500ms timeout.

Comment: I would try to increase the timeout to something like 15 seconds.  It could be the actual number of connections thats causing problems.  500ms may cause usability issues if a user has a slow internet connection anyway.

Comment: Also, if you're running a local IIS server on Windows 7 or Vista, I think the maximum number of connections allowed at one time is 10.

Answer (score 0):

Just appending to Shan's answer, which is a good one.

First off, there is obviously a code issue as this is by no means 'normal' behavior for IIS.

That said, you must isolate it as Shan indicated.  For example, given the server itself no longer accepts connections then we can pretty well eliminate javascript as the source of the problem and relegate it to being just a symptom.

Typically when a worker process spins into space like this it is due to either an infinite loop or an issue where multiple threads are trying to lock the same resource.  I bet if you let it run long enough IIS itself will timeout, kill and restart the process.

With that in mind you want to look for any type of multithreaded garbage (which I highly recommend you *don't* do in a web server) or for anything that indicates a tight infinite loop.  A loop is going to become apparent if you execute the requests individually.  A multi-threaded issue will only show up if you happen to get a collision.

Run various performance counters on the web server.  Also, once it locks up, let it sit that way for awhile.  Once IIS performs it's own reset on the worker process go look for indicators in the event log.